# Error handeling when file is not found in nodeJS and Express framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to display multiple html/jade files using node/express.

**I'm trying to create a basic rule for handeling non-existing files.**

If I would write this code I will not handle error responses but it will work:

```
app.get('/art/:project', function(req, res){
        var project = req.param('project');
        res.render('art/' + project);
    });
```

if I'm writing this code it will handle error correctly but for some reason will not display the page when the file DO exist.

```
 app.get('/art/:project', function(req, res){
        var project = req.param('project');
        res.render('art/' + project, function(err, html) {
          if (err) {
            res.redirect('/');
         }
       });
    });
```

What am I missing?

I've found out that this will work but it seems extremely un-efficient:

```
  res.render('art/' + project, function(err, html) {
    console.log(err, html);
    if (err) {
        res.redirect('/');
    } else {
        res.render('art/' + project);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I;ve tried writing in the else block: res.write(html); res.end();
But is it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to check if the file exists before to try to render it.

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/art/:project', function(req, res){
    var project = req.param('project');
    fs.exists('art/' + project + '.jade', function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            res.render('art/' + project);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well check its existence is OK but the doc suggests:

> fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons.
>   There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code.
>
> In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an
>   anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another
>   process may remove the file between the calls to fs.exists() and
>   fs.open(). Just open the file and handle the error when it's not
>   there.

So it's better to catch exception then handle it:

```
try {
    res.render('art/' + project);
} 
catch(e) {
    if (e.code === 'ENOENT')
        res.redirect('/');
    else
        throw e;
}
```